# Core Audio HALOutput audio unit fails to call input callback

Tags: rust, core-audio

I'm trying to record audio using Core Audio on the Mac, but my input callback isn't getting called. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've been searching and trying stuff all day. My code is written in Rust, but hopefully it won't be too hard to follow for C/C++ folks. Here it is:

```
extern crate coreaudio_sys;
#[macro_use]
extern crate objc;

use std::mem::size_of_val;
use std::os::raw::c_void;
use std::ptr;

use coreaudio_sys::*;
use objc::runtime::{Object, Class};

#[link(name = "Foundation", kind = "framework")] 
extern {}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        // First, create an audio unit.
        let desc = AudioComponentDescription {
            componentType: kAudioUnitType_Output,
            componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput,
            componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
            ..AudioComponentDescription::default()
        };

        let mut au_hal: AudioComponentInstance = ptr::null_mut();
        let comp = AudioComponentFindNext(ptr::null_mut(), &desc);
        assert_ne!(comp, ptr::null_mut());

        let mut code: OSStatus;

        code = AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &mut au_hal);
        assert_eq!(code, 0);

        // Next, enable IO for input.
        let enable_io: UInt32 = 1;
        code = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            au_hal,
            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
            kAudioUnitScope_Input,
            1,
            &enable_io as *const _ as *const _,
            size_of_val(&enable_io) as u32,
        );
        assert_eq!(code, 0);

        // Set the input callback.
        let input = AURenderCallbackStruct {
            inputProc: Some(input_proc),
            inputProcRefCon: ptr::null_mut(),
        };
        code = AudioUnitSetProperty(
            au_hal,
            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
            kAudioUnitScope_Global,
            1,
            &input as *const _ as *const _,
            size_of_val(&input) as u32,
        );
        assert_eq!(code, 0);

        // Finally, initialize and start the unit.
        code = AudioUnitInitialize(au_hal);
        assert_eq!(code, 0);

        code = AudioOutputUnitStart(au_hal);
        assert_eq!(code, 0);

        // Edit: As per Rhythmic Fistman's answer, use an
        // NSRunLoop instead of a "loop {}".
        // This code translates to [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run]; in ObjC.
        //
        // This did not solve my problem.
        let NSRunLoop = Class::get("NSRunLoop").unwrap();
        let run_loop: *mut Object = msg_send![NSRunLoop, mainRunLoop];
        msg_send![run_loop, run];
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes, my `input_proc` callback just returns 0 after printing "hi input":

```
unsafe extern "C" fn input_proc(
    in_ref_con: *mut c_void,
    io_action_flags: *mut AudioUnitRenderActionFlags,
    in_time_stamp: *const AudioTimeStamp,
    in_bus_number: UInt32,
    in_number_frames: UInt32,
    io_data: *mut AudioBufferList,
) -> OSStatus {
    println!("hi input");
    0
}
```

Therefore, I would expect to see "hi input" get printed repeatedly to the console. In reality, nothing gets printed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Mac, you need to tell the `AudioUnit` which audio device to use. In my case I had to disable speaker output on the unit - probably because the default input device on my Mac does input only.

In C (I imagine the Rust version will need a few `as *const _ as *const _`s and `as u32`s):

```c
// disable output (needed, otherwise I can't set device)
flag = 0;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &flag, sizeof(flag));
assert(noErr == err);

// get default input device
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propAddr = {
    .mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice,
    .mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    .mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
};

AudioDeviceID deviceID;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(deviceID);
err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propAddr, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &deviceID);
assert(noErr == err);

// set audio unit current device
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &deviceID, sizeof(deviceID));
assert(noErr == err);
```

In its entirety:

```c
static OSStatus
AUInputCallback(
    void*                       inRefCon,
    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags* ioActionFlags,
    const AudioTimeStamp*       inTimeStamp,
    UInt32                      inBusNumber,
    UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
    AudioBufferList*            ioData)
{
    printf("poot\n");
    return noErr;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    AudioComponentDescription desc = {
        .componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output,
        .componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput,
        .componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
        .componentFlags = 0,
        .componentFlagsMask = 0
    };

    AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);
    assert(comp);

    AudioUnit au;
    OSStatus err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &au);
    assert(noErr == err);

    // enable input
    UInt32      flag = 1;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    assert(noErr == err);

    // disable output (needed, otherwise I can't set device)
    flag = 0;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    assert(noErr == err);

    AURenderCallbackStruct cb;
    cb.inputProc = AUInputCallback;
    cb.inputProcRefCon = NULL;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 1, &cb, sizeof(cb));
    assert(noErr == err);

    // set audio unit device to default input device
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propAddr = {
        .mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice,
        .mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        .mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    AudioDeviceID deviceID;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(deviceID);
    err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propAddr, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &deviceID);
    assert(noErr == err);

    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &deviceID, sizeof(deviceID));
    assert(noErr == err);

    err = AudioUnitInitialize(au);
    assert(noErr == err);

    err = AudioOutputUnitStart(au);
    assert(noErr == err);

    while (1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good call, that never occurred to me. That didn't seem to solve my problem though, unfortunately. I tried adding the equivalent of the following ObjC code in Rust via the `objc` crate: `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];` and I get the same result (no output). Is that what you had in mind? I also tried `CFRunLoopRun`, and that didn't work either.

Comment: I've updated the original question to include my code for your suggestion.

Comment: Updated the answer, infinite loops seem fine after all.